# How to resolve nested name specifier?

Tags: c++, class

For example, I have a A.h header file, and there's a class declaration in it, like:

```
class A {
public:
    struct Node {
        int val;
    };
private:
    B* b;
};
```

It includes a pointer of class B which is defined in B.h file:

```
class B {
public:
    A::Node* node_new() { ***};
};
```

When I compile the project, there's a "nested name specifier" error. How to resolve it?

Comment: Don't you think this will create a recursive relation between the two which never ends?

Comment: There are forward declarations (decl of B in A.h and include B.h in A.h)?

Comment: wtb a .cpp file. I think you're gonna need one.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ yes, I know that. But how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Compiles fine for me when placing the forward declaration `class B;` at the top, defining `node_new() { return new A::Node(); }`, and implementing a simple `int main() { B b; A::Node * an = b.node_new(); }` - no compiler error occurs.  (VS 2012)

Comment: @ForEveR yes, A.h includes #include"B.h" and B.h includes #include "A.h". Also, there's forward decoration for class B in A.h, and the same with B.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> yes, A.h includes #include"B.h" and B.h includes #include "A.h"

So, it's infinite recursion here... You should use forward declaration of class `B` in `A.h` file and include `A.h` in `B.h`, so, this should works fine.